# Can't figure out how to create array of even numbers out of another array in ASM

Tags: assembly, x86

```
assume cs:code, ds:data
data segment
    array db 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
    l equ ($-array)
    d1 db l dup(0) ;array even elements
;   d2 db l dup(0) ; array uneven elements

data ends

code segment
start:
        mov ax, data
        mov ds, ax

        mov si, offset array 
        mov di, 0 


        mov cl, 7
        mov ch, 0

        cld

        build_array:

            LODSB
            or al, 0b ; trigger PF
            JPE array_even ; if the number its even

            array_even:
                mov d1[di], al
                inc di



        loop build_array



        mov ax, 4c00h
        int 21h
code ends
end start
```

So basically I'm trying to create d1 and d2 which are arrays of even and uneven elements. My plan is to first create d1 then d2. However my attempts to create d1 are not working and I'm pretty sure if I get some help I can do d2 by myself.
I'm pretty clueless tho.

Comment: For starters, parity is not what you think, it will not tell you if the number is even, it will tell you if there is an even number of 1 bits in it. You want `test al, 1; jz even`.

Comment: Thanks man, I've tried editing using your suggestion and during every loop it seems to increase di, not only when the number is even.
It did the same thing with JPE.

Should I just put array_even: out of the loop or smh?

Comment: Of course it does, your code doesn't have 2 cases, execution continues to `array_even` anyway. You need a branch that skips the store and goes to the line with the `loop`.

Comment: I see. That makes sense but how to do that? Sorry if that sounds foolish but I'm really lost here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you need two jumps: one conditional, and one unconditional.

Sometimes, you can have your conditional branch could go straight to the top of the loop, allowing the other case to fall through and finish the rest of the loop.  However, in your case you still need to check the loop condition, to not lose count of your source array.

A conditional branch *forward*, skipping the stuff you don't want to do, is the best way to implement an `if`.

```
do {
    int var = a[i];
    if (! (var&1)) {  // test reg, 1 / jz forwards
      *(even++) = var;
    }
} while(++i < n);
```

[`gcc -Og` on godbolt compiles a similar function to asm very similar to what you want](http://goo.gl/IGWnp5).  But it's only using `-Og`, not `-O2`, so there's room for improvement.  `-O3` unrolls the whole loop.